# Android Flipboard animation

Tags: android, xml, animation

I want to animate a Flipboard while changing views in Android.

Is it possible to animate a Flipboard on whole layout? Something similar to those letters on the picture but the whole layout.

For example:

```
<LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">

// whole layout design

<LinearLayout/>
```

I would like to make an animation when changing this Layout and/or inflating another to do the Flipboard animation.

[image: Flipboard animation]

The animation should look exactly like [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w1fTI7oYfbI)

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android-3d-flip-view-transition/

Comment: @dilix I am looking for Animation like this one http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w1fTI7oYfbI

Comment: I think this post is helpful: http://openaphid.github.com/blog/2012/05/21/how-to-implement-flipboard-animation-on-android/

Comment: @dilix Do you got any idea how I am supposed to do this between two activities? This is only for Layouts and Views..

Comment: I think you can use fragments - fragment is stored in view and can contain something like activity =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer of this Question is on GitHub. Very nice example provided by OpenAphid. Visit this [link](https://github.com/openaphid/android-flip).

Comment: This solution doesnt work between activities, does it?

Comment: @Billda this was asked one year ago, till now you can find another way to do this animation, and, uhm, I haven't tried that since everything is going around with fragments.

Comment: I believe you, but i dont know how to implement it with fragments neither .. Because openAphid solution works within single activity/fragment, right?

Answer (score 1):

Use following Codes They are exactly for your requirement:

Class 1:

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.Animation;

    /**
     * A class that is responsible switching the mode with the flip animation 
     */

    public class ViewSwitcher {

        private final static int DURATION = 500;
        private final static float DEPTH = 400.0f;

        public interface AnimationFinishedListener {
            /**
             * Called when the animation is finished.
             */
            public void onAnimationFinished();
        }

        public static void animationIn(View container, WindowManager windowManager) {
            animationIn(container, windowManager, null);
        }

        public static void animationIn(View container, WindowManager windowManager, AnimationFinishedListener listener) {
            apply3DRotation(90, 0, false, container, windowManager, listener);
        }

        public static void animationOut(View container, WindowManager windowManager) {
            animationOut(container, windowManager, null);
        }

        public static void animationOut(View container, WindowManager windowManager, AnimationFinishedListener listener) {
            apply3DRotation(0, -90, true, container, windowManager, listener);
        }

        private static void apply3DRotation(float fromDegree, float toDegree, boolean reverse, View container, WindowManager windowManager, final AnimationFinishedListener listener) {
            Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
            final float centerX = display.getWidth() / 2.0f;
            final float centerY = display.getHeight() / 2.0f;

            final Rotate3dAnimation a = new Rotate3dAnimation(fromDegree, toDegree, centerX, centerY, DEPTH, reverse);
            a.reset();
            a.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            a.setDuration(DURATION);
            a.setFillAfter(true);
            a.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
            if (listener != null) {
                a.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    }

                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                    }

                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        listener.onAnimationFinished();
                    }
                });
            }
            if(container != null){
                container.clearAnimation();
                container.startAnimation(a);
            }
            else if (listener != null)
                listener.onAnimationFinished();
        }
    }
```

class 2:

```
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Transformation;
import android.graphics.Camera;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;

/**
 * An animation that rotates the view on the Y axis between two specified angles.
 * This animation also adds a translation on the Z axis (depth) to improve the effect.
 */
public class Rotate3dAnimation extends Animation {
    private final float mFromDegrees;
    private final float mToDegrees;
    private final float mCenterX;
    private final float mCenterY;
    private final float mDepthZ;
    private final boolean mReverse;
    private Camera mCamera;

    /**
     * Creates a new 3D rotation on the Y axis. The rotation is defined by its
     * start angle and its end angle. Both angles are in degrees. The rotation
     * is performed around a center point on the 2D space, definied by a pair
     * of X and Y coordinates, called centerX and centerY. When the animation
     * starts, a translation on the Z axis (depth) is performed. The length
     * of the translation can be specified, as well as whether the translation
     * should be reversed in time.
     *
     * @param fromDegrees the start angle of the 3D rotation
     * @param toDegrees the end angle of the 3D rotation
     * @param centerX the X center of the 3D rotation
     * @param centerY the Y center of the 3D rotation
     * @param reverse true if the translation should be reversed, false otherwise
     */
    public Rotate3dAnimation(float fromDegrees, float toDegrees,
            float centerX, float centerY, float depthZ, boolean reverse) {
        super.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        mFromDegrees = fromDegrees;
        mToDegrees = toDegrees;
        mCenterX = centerX;
        mCenterY = centerY;
        mDepthZ = depthZ;
        mReverse = reverse;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
        super.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
        mCamera = new Camera();
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        super.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        final float fromDegrees = mFromDegrees;
        float degrees = fromDegrees + ((mToDegrees - fromDegrees) * interpolatedTime);

        final float centerX = mCenterX;
        final float centerY = mCenterY;
        final Camera camera = mCamera;
        final Matrix matrix = t.getMatrix();

        camera.save();
        if (mReverse) {
            camera.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, mDepthZ * interpolatedTime);
        } else {
            camera.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, mDepthZ * (1.0f - interpolatedTime));
        }
        camera.rotateX(degrees);
        camera.getMatrix(matrix);
        camera.restore();

        matrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY);
        matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);

    }
}
```

Class 3:

```
This Will be Your Actual activity where you should call following two calls to AnimationOut and AnimationIn with passing old view, new view respectively whenever you require to make your disered animation.
```

Now Call the animationOut with first argument as the Old view to be removed like below:

```
ViewSwitcher.animationOut(this.findViewById(android.R.id.content1), getWindowManager(), new ViewSwitcher.AnimationFinishedListener() {
            public void onAnimationFinished() {
            //Do Something here before removing this view from screen if required.
            }
        });
```

Now Call the animationIn with first argument as the new view to be shown like below:

```
ViewSwitcher.animationIn(this.findViewById(android.R.id.content2), this.getWindowManager());
```

Comment: I did upvoted but I am still trying to configure this animation to split my View in half and do the exact I am looking for. Btw the snipped is awesome. I will Accept the answer if I manage to split the view in half :)

Comment: The Animation should look exactly like this one http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w1fTI7oYfbI ..

Comment: @Naskov To Split your View in half and do the exact change the angles.i think that can do it.